# How to use LocationListener in MVVM?

Tags: android, android-location, android-mvvm

I want to make the app to jogging with MVVM pattern, but I don't have idea where to put LocationListener. How to correctly use LocationListener together with MVVM? Repository?
For the testing I've created something like this. It's only test to check the operation and it works fine, but this not MVVM.

```
class GPSLocationListener(private var activity: MainActivity) : LocationListener {

lateinit var location: Location

override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
    val speed : Double = (location!!.speed * 3600 / 1000).toDouble()
    activity.updateUI(speed)
    this.location = location
}

override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String?) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String?) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
}
```

Comment: You don't *have* to strictly apply MVVM throughout your whole app, on every piece of data that intervenes within it. GPS Location is something that is can be heavily tied to the platform the code is running on, hence it's can be hard to integrate it with MVVM. I suggest you keep onLocationChanged as is, and you call a function within it to notify there was a change (pretty much like you did). Every data doesn't have to be in a repository.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

passing view(main activity) reference to `GPSLocationListener` is a wrong approach because it might be a reason for memory leak(take a look at [this](https://proandroiddev.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-memory-leaks-in-android-d7a59faaf46a) about memory leak to understand better)

on the other hand listening device's location is tied to **Android platform** so it should be handled in `activity` or `fragment`

if you'll be performing heavy operation with the result of location request you should use view model along with RxJava or Coroutines and then you should listen your data(wrapped in LiveData) in your view(activity-fragment)

Comment: true about the activity reference but it would be good to explain why

Comment: So I should use it in normal Activity where I need it?

Comment: yeah just implement your LocationListener in your activity directly

Comment: I just edited my answer just look at the link that I attached there to understand why you shouldn't pass view reference into other layer of the application

Comment: What do you think is a heavy operation @ZaferCelaloglu ? I'm trying to calculate the distance between a start position and a new one and I don't know where do this. I am learning Android, I really appreciate your help :)